# All my subdomains which I haven't setup on server loads my phpmyadmin virtualhost configuration by default

Tags: server, apache2, dns, phpmyadmin

I have done setting up a sub-domain on my ubuntu server for my phpmyadmin, which is working fine.
If I created a new sub-domain in my DNS and make it to point on the ubuntu server loads my phpmyadmin page by default.

I know, if I created a new virtualhost settings for the newly created sub-domain will also working respectively, but the thing here is I want to load a default page on unknown domains/sub-domains instead of loading my phpmyadmin.

Example:

> http://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com - loading phpmyadmin which is working good

> http://newsubdomain.mydomain.com - also loading phpmyadmin settings by default, which I don't want to show off

My phpmyadmin virtualhost configuration as follows for reference,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin manoj@mydomain.com
    ServerName phpmyadmin.mydomain.com
    # Redirect permanent / https://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com/
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.mydomain.com-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin.mydomain.com-error.log
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Suggest me to load default webpage configuration for the upcoming domains too intead of showing my phpmyadmin page.

My `000-default.conf` file details as follows,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin manoj@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ErrorDocument 403 /exceptions/custom_403.php # working fine when it occurs
    ErrorDocument 404 /exceptions/custom_404.php # working fine
    ErrorDocument 500 /exceptions/custom_50x.php # working fine
    ErrorDocument 502 /exceptions/custom_50x.php # working fine
    ErrorDocument 503 /exceptions/custom_50x.php # working fine
    ErrorDocument 504 /exceptions/custom_50x.php # working fine
</VirtualHost>
```

and, I already enabled this default site too

Comment: By default you should have `000-default.conf` in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory. Can you check if it is there and edit your question with it's content.

Comment: Hi @sotirov - As you asked for I updated my question with `000-default.conf` content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several searching time I do concluded this problem with my own understanding.

Actually I already done setting up the main domain with SSL and I enabled the 443 port on for `phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` which is already chosen by default.

That's the issue cause. So, now I'm created a default virtualhost setting for the port 443 which loading to its default page finely.